# Matrix multiplied by mod p

Tags: matrices

I was reading the following paper and I am stuck at the second last step. Can you please explain  the `L multiplied by (mod 19) step` (right after (6)) [image]

How are they getting `(3/5)mod 19 =12` ? similarly how are they getting the other matrix elements `16`, `3`, `12` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplicative inverse of 5 is 4 mod 19 like how the paper says. So instead of dividing by 5, you can just multiply by 4 and then reduce modulo 19 if the result is too large.

3*4=12

4*4=16

-4*4=-16=3 (mod 19)

Comment: ok got it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you operate in a ring where $5$ is invertible, then the inverse of the matrix
$$\left( \begin{matrix} \frac{3}{5}& \frac{4}{5}\\
            -\frac{4}{5} & \frac{3}{5} \end{matrix} \right) $$
is its transpose
$$\left( \begin{matrix} \frac{3}{5}& -\frac{4}{5}\\
            \frac{4}{5} & \frac{3}{5} \end{matrix} \right) $$
(everything works fine; you only use $3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2$)

Now $\mod 19$ ( in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/19$) the inverse of $5$ is $4$ ( depends on that $\mod n$ you are dealing with; say $\!\! \mod 7$ we have $5^{-1} = 3$). Therefore your matrix $\mod 19$ is
$$\left( \begin{matrix} 3\cdot 4& -4\cdot 4\\
            4\cdot 4 & 3\cdot 4 \end{matrix} \right)= \left( \begin{matrix} 12& 3\\
            16 & 12 \end{matrix} \right)$$
with inverse (again) equal to its transpose
$$\left( \begin{matrix} 12& 16\\
            3 & 12 \end{matrix} \right)$$